# Table empty on page load knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

So I am using a searchbox to search for specific data from the table. But the problem I am having is that when the page loads the table is empty, so what is the best way to load the table with data even if the is no value entered in the search box for the specific one and should show all data on the table.
I am searching the data from the Array.

```
self.TransactionList = ko.observableArray(self.transactiondatas());
        self.Query = ko.observable("");
        self.Query.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (!(value && value.trim())) {
            self.TransactionList(self.transactiondatas());
            return;
        }
        var data = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.transactiondatas(), function (item) {
        if (item.transaction_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        self.TransactionList(data);
        });

        /* Function for intializing the TransactionViewModel view-model */
        self.InitializeTransactionViewModel = function () {           
            self.transactiondatas.removeAll();
           $.getJSON(BASEURL + 'index.php/account/TransactionData/' + auth , function (transactions) {
             $.each(transactions, function (index, transaction) {
                    self.transactiondatas.push( transaction);
                });
                // holds the total transactiondatas count
                self.TotalNumberOfTransactiondatas(self.transactiondatas().length);
                // initialize the Money Requests and Offers available table
                self.searchTransactiondatas();
           });  
       };
       self.InitializeTransactionViewModel();
      // this part above tries to push the data but the table does not populate because of the Query
```

This is the input on the `html view`

```
<input  data-bind="value: Query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"   type="search" class="form-control text-center"  placeholder="Search transaction type">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organize your viewmodel like this:

```
// data properties
self.transactiondatas = ko.observableArray();
self.query = ko.observable();

// computed properties
self.totalNumberOfTransactiondatas = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return self.transactiondatas().length;
});
self.transactionList = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var value = $.trim( self.query() ).toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.transactiondatas(), function (item) {
        return !value || item.transaction_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
});

// API functions
self.initializeTransactionViewModel = function () {
    var url = BASEURL + 'index.php/account/TransactionData/' + auth;
    $.getJSON(url).done(self.transactiondatas);
};

// init
self.initializeTransactionViewModel();
self.query("");
```

Notes:

- `totalNumberOfTransactiondatas` is a perfect fit for a computed property, don't calculate/set that manually.
- The same goes for `transactionList` - the transaction list is a direct function of the values of `transactiondatas` and `query`, there is no need to *manually* maintain a separate list of transaction items.
- `ko.pureComputed()` has been introduced in Knockout 3.2.0. Use regular `ko.computed()` for older versions.
- Knockout observables are functions. That means you can use them as callbacks. `$.getJSON(url).done(self.transactiondatas);` elegantly replaces your entire sequence of `.removeAll()` and `$.each()` + `.push()`.
- Setting `self.query("")` during viewmodel initialization triggers a recalculation of `totalNumberOfTransactiondatas` and `transactionList`. The same happens again when the JSON arrives a few moments later.

Comment: I tried , it did not work, basically did not load anything on the page

Comment: Check your console for errors. Also note that I have renamed your variables - only constructors should start with a capital letters. Don't copy and paste code. Read and understand.

Comment: Observables as callbacks, that's elegant. I'm not sure I'd use it though because it deprives you of the opportunity to do anything *else*.

Comment: yes I noticed those changes, and I took the codes, and worked, and the error I was getting is Uncaught TypeError: ko.pureComputed is not a function

Comment: I even fixed it by writing ko.computed, but now the console doesnt show any errrors, I alerted but looks like there is nothing getting returned.

Comment: @Peter No, it won't. `$.get(url).then(transformationFunction).done(targetObservable);`

Comment: @Farhana Yes, `pureComputed` are an addition of Knockout 3.2.0 - I assumed that you would use a recent version of the library.

Comment: @Tomalak so basically it gets stuck here 
var value = (self.query() || "").trim().toLowerCase(); ,  it doesnt show anything at that point

Comment: I don't know what `.trim()` is, I took that from your code. It's not a standard JS function. Maybe you meant to use `$.trim()` all along? Also, double check the capitalization, your code has `Query`, not `query`.

Comment: @Farhana I've changed it to us `$.trim()` now, this function handles undefined and null gracefully and it's available through jQuery.

Comment: Now I am getting transactionlist not defined

Comment: Yes, that's because it's called `transactionList`. I've said it three times now, double check the variable name spelling.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes I wrote that, `transactionList` I checked all spelling, I was writing it quickly so wrote transactionlist to you, but it still says not defined.

Comment: @Tomalak it worked, my apache directory did not get updated with my netbeans code, hence all the problems occured, Sorry for disturbing you so much but the codes worked! Thanks!

Comment: That's all-right, good to hear you got it working. I was a bit confused because I was pretty sure that there were no mistakes in my snippet.

Comment: Yea I guess you thought I was making spelling mistakes haha, but anyways Thanks!

Comment: @tomalak - the semantics of then and done are not the same. I could subscribe to the observable and put the extra code there but that still entails another function and it's less clear. As cute as this is, I think you're perilously close to demonstrating the difference been clever and smart. Don't get me wrong, I find it aesthetically appealing, but my common sense is saying no.

Comment: @Peter I know the semantics are different, that's why I use two different functions. If you want to pre-process the server result (e.g. converting dates in JSON or creating sub-viewmodel instances), use `.then()`. I don't see how subscriptions fit here. But that's not the point. This: `.then(function (data) { someObservable(data); })` is a common pattern and there is nothing particularly "clever" with replacing it with its equivalent, `.then(someObservable)`. You'd do that with any other function that is not called "observable", so why not here.

Comment: @tomalak Good question. The answer is essentially one of code clarity which is entirely subjective.

Comment: @PeterWone BTW, even Steve Sanderson himself does it, for whatever that's worth. Compare https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/asynchronous-dependent-observables#manually-capturing-the-asynchronous-result